# XSL: how to check if any of the ancestors of the current node is a specific node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say that we have this XML:

```
          <ce:table id="table2">
                <ce:label>Table 2</ce:label>
                <ce:caption >
                    <ce:simple-para >Hello</ce:simple-para>
                </ce:caption>
                <ce:alt-text >Table 2</ce:alt-text>
                <tgroup cols="2">
                    <colspec colname="col1"/>
                    <colspec colname="col2"/>
                    <thead valign="top">
                        <row rowsep="1">
                            <entry align="left">Sub1</entry>
                            <entry align="left">Sub2</entry>
                        </row>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <row>
                            <entry role="rowhead" align="left">
                                <ce:list id="list1">

                                </ce:list>
                            </entry>
                        </row>
                    </tbody>
                </tgroup>
            </ce:table>
```

How to check if `ce:table` node has a `ce:list` node in this case the XSLT condition should return true.

Any ideas!

Comment: It is easy using XML Linq which has a Descendant method.

Comment: Hm, why did you edit out part of your original question?

Comment: @Tomalak its not relevant :)

Comment: It is, because for example my answer took direct reference to your attempt, explaining why it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current node is

```
/data/ce:table
```

you can check the existence of a `ce:list` subnode with

```
<xsl:if test=".//ce:list">
```

`.//` means all nodes descending from current node, without considering depth.

Comment: .//ce:list this what I exactly needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select descendants with XPath then use e.g. `ce:table/descendant::ce:list` or `ce:table//ce:list`. Inside the `test` attribute that selection would then yield true if any such node exists.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this:

```
<xsl:when test="ce:table/*[local-name() = 'ce:list'] ">
```

Didn't work, because

- `local-name()` explicitly gives you names without prefixes, it would never return `ce:list`
- the `ce:list` you refer to is not a direct child of `ce:table`, but a descendant.

> How to check if ce:table node has a ce:list node

Like this:

```
<xsl:when test="ce:table//ce:list"> ... </xsl:when>
```

Checking for the existence of a node is done by writing an XPath expression that selects it. If the node does not exist, the expression returns an empty node-set, which evaluates to `false` in a Boolean context.

Boolean contexts are the tests in `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>`, but also the predicates in a more complex XPath expression:

```
ce:table[.//ce:list]/ce:label
```

selects all `<ce:label>` children of `<ce:table>`, but only under the condition that that `<ce:table>` has a `<ce:list>` descendant somewhere.